# Can diols be oxidised to hydroxyacids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, carboxylic-acids

#### Conversion of ethanol to ethanoic acid

$
\ce{CH3CH2OH_{(aq)}
  \xrightarrow[KMnO^{-}_{4}]{NaOH}
  CH3CHO_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)}
}\\
$

$\ce{CH3CHO_{(aq)} + H+_{(aq)}
  \xrightarrow[KMnO^{-}_{4}]{HCl}
  CH3COOH_{(aq)}
}$

Are the steps above correct

Can I apply the above steps when the starting reagent is a diol?

I can't find any information about this on google.

#### Diol to hydroxy-acid

$
\ce{
  ethane-1,2-diol_{(aq)}
  \rightarrow
  \alpha-hydroxyethanoic acid_{(aq)}
}
$

Equation is not balanced, just shows the reaction I want to do.

Comment: This will give oxalic acid.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how I can produce a hydroxyacid? Is the first reaction valid for producing a carboxylic acid? Also could you write an answer so I can give credit? Compared to other stackexchanges, chem is very quick to downvote without explanations, perhaps you could explain the downvotes?

Comment: You want an explanation? If this was a homework, then it would be lame. For actual synthesis, it doesn't make sense at all. I think Waylander explained why.

Comment: yep it is for synthesis, I understand him now

Comment: can you see my last question to waylander and help me as to how I can avoid downvotes as I need to keep asking question (graduated chemistry 10 yrs ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly no-one runs this reaction with ethane-1,2-diol (ethylene glycol) because glycolic acid is widely available. However if you want to run the oxidation of a primary alcohol to carboxylic acid in the presence of an alcohol elsewhere in your molecule you need to develop a protection strategy so that the alcohol you want to keep as an alcohol is temporarily turned into something else which will not react and can then be **easily** returned to alcohol. This is an important part of synthetic organic chemistry. There are whole books written about this e.g. Greene's Protection Groups in Organic Synthesis  [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118905074).

A suitable group for alcohol protection under basic permanganate oxidation conditions would be the tetrahydropyran ether, more details [here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/protectivegroups/hydroxyl/thp-ethers.htm)

If you have 2 primary alcohols then you have a challenge in finding conditions so that only one reacts to form the protection group.

Comment: thanks but I'm more interested in using the diol to make glycolic acid, where I live I can't find glycolic acid, whereas ethan-1,2-diol is readily available and cheap. Using your source can I apply the same steps for the alcohol to carboxylic acid for a diol to hydroxyacid?

Comment: Also I don't understand why you would want the the temporary molecule (aldehyde?) to turn back in to the alcohol.

Comment: It should be possible to make the mono-THP ether of ethylene glycol from a 1.05:1 mixture of ethylene glycol and dihydropyran where the bulk of the material is mono-protected and the unprotected material is easily removed after the oxidation.

Comment: You want to be able to turn the temporary molecule back to the alcohol because you need the alcohol group in the final molecule or for a further transformation

Comment: ah I see so this cuts out the step of second oxidation? I am still confused `alcohol + [O] -> aldehyde + water` then ```aldehyde + [O] -> carboxylic acid``` that's how I understand the process so can you explain further so I understand your reasoning of turning the aldehyde back into the alcohol

Comment: sorry `aldehyde + H^{+} + [O] -> carboxylic acid` I think you're using a more advanced procedure, that's why I don't understand

Comment: basic permanganate takes the primary alcohol direct to carboxylic acid. If you want the aldehyde use a different oxidation agent

Comment: ok I understand the protection now, it's to protect 1 of the hydroxyl groups so with a diol there is a difference thank you

Comment: Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: of course, I just have 1 questions before I delve in to your sources, when protecting the hydroxyl group, how can I be sure that both will not be protected?

Comment: I graduated chemistry 10 yrs ago, online sources had nothing on diol conversion, I have some textbooks but because I've been out of chemistry so long (I code now) I still need guidance. Any advice on why this question got so many downvotes and how I can avoid it in the future, as I'd like to keep asking questions. Protection never would've crossed my mind and I may have missed it despite reading my textbooks. Any reasons you might have downvoted it? I'd like to keep in touch with you as you didn't just scoff the question off like most people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147272/discussion-between-waylander-and-nickotine).